# What's wrong with these simple android lines?

Tags: android

can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this:

```
package applicationTest.ppr.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainClass extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("Merdas para teste");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    } 
}
```

my main.xml and android manifest are good. the app crashes when i added the textview stuff, and altered the default text specified in my main.xml. If I remove this, the app works.. but I can't figure out why...

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

you should before get any view , set the Content of your activity 
 so try this :

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText("Merdas para teste");


}
```

Comment: lol.. it was that simple... -.-"
my logic was to display the stuff after changing the values ;)

obviously setContentView does more than that.
Thank you! ;)

Comment: I was wondering who would be the fastest and you have won - +1 from me :)

Comment: you are welcome  FRed, Glad to help ;) 
Note: you should set The content First, the problem in your code , is that you try to get a View ( TextView ) before u didn't set the content of your activity, so it will return NULL , ;)

Comment: @Lumis : lol , very funny , ;) 
 where are here to help each other, this is the reason of StackOverFlow
@Fred : Vote the question  , that's simple for others to get Help

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setContentView` *before* calling `findViewById`.

`SetContentView` is what builds the views and attaches it to the window.  Since you have the calls reversed, `findViewById` is probably returning null, causing the `setText` call to throw an NPE.

Comment: hi, I read your answer last. lol. But yeah that makes sense ; D
thank you both!

Comment: No worries :)  Glad you could get your question answered!